# GIT: How to remove deleted files from commit list?

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch that contains the following 3 files:

```
- a.txt  
- b.txt  
- c.txt
```

suppose i create a new branch from this master by running following command:

```
>git checkout -b dev
```

now, dev branch will also have these 3 files. But I do not want c.txt file in this branch so I delete it by running:

```
>git rm c.txt
```

now, running `>git status` would show that I have one deleted file and it needs to be committed. But I don't want to commit it nor I want it to show in my deleted file list when I run `>git status`

What do I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want then? If you delete a tracked file then git will you tell about it. Do you want to hide the status output but still delete it?

Comment: "Do you want to hide the status output but still delete it?" - Yes, thats exactly i want to do. Any solution?

Comment: Take a look at [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/).

Answer (score 1):

**git rm** deletes the file add marks it as staged. To activate the change you HAVE to commit the deletion, and if you have a remote also push this new commit to the remote.

Comment: Exactly. You're committing the delete, not the file.

Comment: @Don Branson, But when u commit and push those deleted changes to the dev branch, and later then u merge dev to master, those deleted files will also get deleted from the master. Thats what I do not want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that from your original question. Probably you'll want to do the deletes as a their own commit, then apply changes from the branch with a patch instead of merging. Skip that delete commit when you create the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to commit the deletion? If you want your new branch to have different files from the old one, it's going to have to have a different commit history. You either need a new commit that records your deletion, or you need to edit the history of the new branch so that some previous commit deletes the file (or avoids creating it in the first place).

Comment: when u commit and push those deleted changes to the dev branch, and later then u merge dev to master, those deleted files will also get deleted from the master. Thats what I do not want.

Comment: I see. One option is to use `cherry-pick` or a more complicated `rebase` to move just the commits you want onto master. But in general, maintaining parallel-but-not-identical histories is hard, and it confuses lots of tools. It's more like having a second independent project than it is like having a branch. Is there a way to accomplish what you need without actually deleting the file from history? Maybe a configuration change that you can make when you're working in `dev`?